# Dúvida query - SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Boa tarde!

Galera, não sei se é possível, mas queria saber como faço para que um registro de uma linha fique em outra linha. Vou exemplificar. Na consulta abaixo está saindo assim.

```
         Projeto                   Operadora
Telles - Bronze - Climario      Habilitação Cielo.
Telles - Bronze - Climario      Habilitação Rede.
```

Queria saber se teria como ficar da seguinte forma.

```
ProjDesc                             Operadora
Telles - Bronze - Climario      Habilitação Cielo e Habilitação Rede.
```

ou seja, juntar a habilitação rede que está na linha abaixo na mesma linha da habilitação Cielo. Segue abaixo a query utilizada.

```
SELECT p.projdesc,
       CONCAT('Faltando ', tt.tartitulo)
  FROM projetos p
       INNER JOIN tarefa tt ON p.projid = tt.projid
       LEFT JOIN tipo c ON c.tipid = tt.tartipid
 WHERE tt.tarstatus <> 9
   AND p.projid = tt.projid
   AND c.tipdescricao LIKE 'Habilita%'
   AND tt.projid = p.projid
   AND tt.modid = 181
   AND tt.tartipid IN (867, 868, 869, 870,
                       871, 872, 873, 874,
                       875, 876, 877, 878,
                       879, 880, 881, 882,
                       883, 884, 885, 886,
                       887, 888, 889, 890,
                       891, 892, 893, 894,
                       895, 896, 897, 898,
                       899, 900, 901, 902,
                       903, 904, 905, 906,
                       907, 908, 909, 910,
                       911, 912, 913, 914,
                       915, 916, 917, 918,
                       919, 920, 921, 922,
                       923, 924, 925, 926,
                       927, 928, 929, 930,
                       931, 932, 933, 934,
                       1004, 1034)
```

Comment: Tem como disponibilizar o Schema das tabelas?

Comment: veja https://groupconcat.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criei um exemplo com uma tabela variável baseado no resultado da sua primeira consulta:

```
DECLARE @tabela TABLE(id        INT IDENTITY,
                      projeto   VARCHAR(100),
                      operadora VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @tabela
SELECT p.projdesc,
       tt.tartitulo
  FROM tarefa tt
       INNER JOIN projetos p ON p.projid = tt.projid
       LEFT JOIN tipo c ON c.tipid = tt.tartipid
 WHERE tt.modid = 181
   AND tt.tarstatus <> 9
   AND (tt.tartipid BETWEEN 867 AND 934
    OR tt.tartipid IN (1004, 1034))
   AND c.tipdescricao LIKE 'Habilita%';

SELECT r.projeto,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t.operadora
                FROM @tabela t
               WHERE t.projeto = r.projeto
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS operadoras
  FROM @tabela r
 GROUP BY projeto;
```

Caso queira realizar a consulta de uma só vez, utilize a expressão `WITH` da seguinte forma:

```
WITH tabela (projeto, operadora) AS (
  SELECT p.projdesc,
         tt.tartitulo
    FROM tarefa tt
         INNER JOIN projetos p ON p.projid = tt.projid
         LEFT JOIN tipo c ON c.tipid = tt.tartipid
   WHERE tt.modid = 181
     AND tt.tarstatus <> 9
     AND (tt.tartipid BETWEEN 867 AND 934
      OR tt.tartipid IN (1004, 1034))
     AND c.tipdescricao LIKE 'Habilita%')

SELECT r.projeto,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t.operadora
                FROM tabela t
               WHERE t.projeto = r.projeto
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') AS operadoras
  FROM tabela r
 GROUP BY projeto;
```

---

**Observação/Melhorias:**

- Simpliquei a restrição da coluna `tartipid` notando que o intervalo entre 867 e 934 é fixo e os códigos que realmente devem ser declarados são o 1004 e 1034;
- Melhorei também a ordem do `WHERE` para utilizar as condições que restringem mais primeiro e colocando o `LIKE` no final, considerando o custo dessa instrução;
- Removi também duas condições que eram redundantes;
- Ajustei a ordem dos `JOIN`s para garantir que a tabela que mais restringe seja buscada primeiramente.

---

**Referência:** [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/273330/3388148)

Comment: ôpa @Sorack , deu certo. Agora estou na duvida de como devo inseri essa consulta dentro dessa consulta abaixo, pois há uma tabela variável e não sei como funciona dessa forma..

SELECT 
 DISTINCT(PP.ProjDesc),
 C.CompDesc QtdeCNPJs,
 U1.UsuUF
   
FROM PROJETOS PP
INNER JOIN Tarefa T ON PP.ProjID = T.ProjID
INNER JOIN Usuario U ON T.UsuIDResponsavel = U.UsuID
INNER JOIN Usuario U1 ON T.UsuIDCliente = U1.UsuID
LEFT JOIN Statusaux S ON T.TarStatus = S.StatusID
LEFT JOIN Complemento C ON C.UsuID = T.UsuIDCliente and C.CompID = 1
WHERE T.Macprocid = 33
      AND T.TarTipID in (866)

Comment: @Sorack: A observação "_Melhorei também a ordem do WHERE para utilizar as condições que restringem mais primeiro e colocando o LIKE no final, considerando o custo dessa instrução_" não está correta. O otimizador de consultas do SQL Server ignora a ordem em que as restrições estão dispostas na cláusula WHERE.

Comment: @Sorack: A observação "_Ajustei a ordem dos JOINs para garantir que a tabela que mais restringe seja buscada primeiramente_" também está incorreta. O otimizador de consultas do SQL Server não leva em consideração a ordem em que as tabelas são definidas na cláusula FROM. // Uma exceção é quando se utiliza a opção FORCE ORDER.